# New User creation script error

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have the script listed below that I can't seem to get the issue worked out of.  I'm trying to make an interactive login script for a UNIX class that I'm in.  I'm basically building out a command to pass into `useradd`.  The command that I make when passed into the command line (while adding `sudo`) works as expected, but when I try to run it from my script (which is generating the text that I copy/paste into the command line) it gives me some errors...  At this point I'm at a loss for what to try next to resolve the issue.

**ERROR:**

```
useradd -m --user-group jaredm2 #command that is attempting to run...
useradd: invalid option -- ' '
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
....rest of useradd error text....
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Add a new user

FINALCOMMAND="-m"

#import useradd defaults...
. /etc/default/useradd

#Check if running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be ran as root"
    exit 1
fi

#Get the new users Name
#echo -n "Please enter the users First and Last Name and press [ENTER]: "
#read Name

#Get the new users username
echo "The username must be 4-20 characters."
echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
read USERNAME
while [ $(grep -c "^${USERNAME}:" /etc/passwd) -ge 1 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -le 3 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -ge 21 ]
do
    echo " "
    echo "Error: Username is in use or invalid.  Please select a different username."
    echo " "
    echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
    read USERNAME   
done #USERNAME will be valid from this point

#ASK about the default shell now
echo -n "Enter the new shell if you would like one (currently $SHELL) or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read tempSHELL
if [ ${#tempSHELL} -ge 1 ]; then
    SHELL="$tempSHELL"
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND ""-s $SHELL"
fi

#ASK about a different primary group
echo "Would you like to enter a non-default primary user group? Defaults to creating a new group that matches the username"
echo "Enter a new Primary Group or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read newPrimaryGroup

if [ ${#newPrimaryGroup} -eq 0 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND --user-group"
else
    if [ $(grep -c "^${newPrimaryGroup}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -g $newPrimaryGroup"
    else
        echo "Invalid group specified reverting to default!"
        FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND --user-group"
    fi
fi
useradd -m --user-group jaredm2
#ASK about additional groups
echo "Would you like the new user to be a part of any additional groups?  Leave blank if no additional groups are needed or enter additional groups in the format of GROUP1,GROUP2,... (NO SPACES) and press [ENTER]: "
read extraGroups
#remove spaces if the user entered any
extraGroups="${extraGroups//[[:space:]]}"
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=""
IFS=","
for g in $extraGroups
do
    if [ $(grep -c "^${g}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALEXTRAGROUPS="$FINALEXTRAGROUPS,$g"
    else
        echo "$g is invalid user will not be added..."
    fi
done
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=$(echo "$FINALEXTRAGROUPS" | tail -c +2)
if [ ${#FINALEXTRAGROUPS} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -G $FINALEXTRAGROUPS"
fi

#ASK about the home directory
echo "Would you like to enter a new home directory for the user?  Leave blank to use the default of $HOME/$USERNAME or enter your own and press [ENTER]: "
read NEWHOME

if [ ${#NEWHOME} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -d $NEWHOME"
fi

#ADD the username to the command
FINALCOMMAND=`echo "$FINALCOMMAND $USERNAME" | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed 's/^ *//g'`
echo "useradd $FINALCOMMAND"
#PASSCOMMAND="sudo passwd $USERNAME"
#ADD THE USER
`useradd $FINALCOMMAND`

`passwd $USERNAME`

`chfn $USERNAME`
```

**UPDATE: ADDED DEBUG CONTENT**

```
+ '[' 0 -ge 1 ']'
++ sed 's/^ *//g'
++ sed 's/ *$//g'
++ echo '/usr/sbin/useradd -m -U JaredM'
+ FINALCOMMAND='/usr/sbin/useradd -m -U JaredM'
++ '/usr/sbin/useradd -m -U JaredM'
./addnewuser.sh: line 89: /usr/sbin/useradd -m -U JaredM: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Without going onto the problem itself, what if you replace `--user-group` with `-U` ? :)

Comment: do `man -s8 useradd` and check if the man page specifies that you have the `--user-group` option available to use. If its not mentioned in man page, then even `-U` will not work.

Comment: @favoretti I have tried both ways with no luck passing either argument.

Comment: Just curious, do you have SELinux or such system protection software running in your system? And could you also share the version of BASH.

Comment: I'll get the version of bash when I get home.  I think the only "protection" software I have is AppArmor, but not sure.  Again, I can look this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using arrays you could prevent IFS related errors in the command-line and it's a lot cleaner. This one's already tested. I made some clean-ups to the code as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Add a new user

FINALCOMMAND=("-m")

#Import useradd defaults...
. /etc/default/useradd

#Check if running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be ran as root"
    exit 1
fi

#Get the new users Name
#echo -n "Please enter the users First and Last Name and press [ENTER]: "
#read Name

#Get the new users username
echo "The username must be 4-20 characters."
echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
read USERNAME
while [ $(grep -c "^${USERNAME}:" /etc/passwd) -ge 1 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -le 3 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -ge 21 ]; do
    echo " "
    echo "Error: Username is in use or invalid.  Please select a different username."
    echo " "
    echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
    read USERNAME
done #USERNAME will be valid from this point

#ASK about the default shell now
echo -n "Enter the new shell if you would like one (currently $SHELL) or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read tempSHELL
if [ ${#tempSHELL} -ge 1 ]; then
    SHELL="$tempSHELL"
    FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "-s" "$SHELL")
fi

#ASK about a different primary group
echo "Would you like to enter a non-default primary user group? Defaults to creating a new group that matches the username"
echo -n "Enter a new Primary Group or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read newPrimaryGroup

if [ ${#newPrimaryGroup} -eq 0 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "--user-group")
else
    if [ $(grep -c "^${newPrimaryGroup}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "-g" "$newPrimaryGroup")
    else
        echo "Invalid group specified reverting to default!"
        FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "--user-group")
    fi
fi

#ASK about additional groups
echo -n "Would you like the new user to be a part of any additional groups?  Leave blank if no additional groups are needed or enter additional groups in the format of GROUP1,GROUP2,... (NO SPACES) and press [ENTER]: "
read extraGroups
#remove spaces if the user entered any
extraGroups="${extraGroups//[[:space:]]}"
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=''
IFS=, read -a TEMP <<< "$extraGroups"
for g in "${TEMP[@]}"; do
    if [ $(grep -c "^${g}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALEXTRAGROUPS="$FINALEXTRAGROUPS,$g"
    else
        echo "$g is invalid user will not be added..."
    fi
done

if [ ${#FINALEXTRAGROUPS[@]} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "-G" "${FINALEXTRAGROUPS:1}")
fi


#ASK about the home directory
echo -n "Would you like to enter a new home directory for the user?  Leave blank to use the default of $HOME/$USERNAME or enter your own and press [ENTER]: "
read NEWHOME

if [ ${#NEWHOME} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "-d" "$NEWHOME")
fi

#ADD the username to the command
FINALCOMMAND=("${FINALCOMMAND[@]}" "$USERNAME")

#PASSCOMMAND="sudo passwd $USERNAME"

#ADD THE USER
echo "useradd ${FINALCOMMAND[@]}"

useradd "${FINALCOMMAND[@]}"

passwd "$USERNAME"

chfn "$USERNAME"
```

Note: In newer versions of bash you could just use += to append a value to an array e.g. ARRAY+=("value")

Also by my additional preferences I would improve the code further this way, but that's not the best of it yet:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

# Check if running as root.
if [[ "$(id -u)" != 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script must be ran as root."
    exit 1
fi

# Initialize useradd command variable.
USERADDCOMMAND=("useradd" "-m")

# Import useradd defaults.
. /etc/default/useradd

# Get the new user's name.
#echo -n "Please enter the users First and Last Name and press [ENTER]: "
#read NAME

# Get the new users username.
echo "The username must be 4-20 characters."
while :; do
    read -p "Please enter the user's requested username and press [ENTER]: " USERNAME
    [[ ${#USERNAME} -ge 4 && ${#USERNAME} -le 20 && $USERNAME == +([[:alpha:]])*([[:alnum:]_-]) ]] || {
        echo "Error: Username is invalid. Please enter a different username."
        continue
    }
    [[ $(grep -c "^${USERNAME}:" /etc/passwd) -ge 1 ]] && {
        echo "Error: Username is in use. Please enter a different username."
        continue
    }
    break
done

# Ask about the default shell.
read -p "Enter the new shell if you would like one (currently $SHELL) or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: " SHELL_
if [[ ${#SHELL_} -ge 1 ]]; then
    USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "-s" "$SHELL_")
else
    # We use this if we really are to use SHELL specified in $SHELL but it still needs further workarounds like checking if $SHELL is valid. Those could be easily done but it depends if this one's really necessary.
    #USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "-s" "$SHELL")
    :
fi

# Ask about a different primary group.
echo "Would you like to enter a non-default primary user group? Defaults to creating a new group that matches the username."
echo -n "Enter a new Primary Group or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read NEWPRIMARYGROUP

if [[ ${#NEWPRIMARYGROUP} -eq 0 ]]; then
    USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "--user-group")
else
    if [[ $(grep -c "^${NEWPRIMARYGROUP}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]]; then
        USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "-g" "$NEWPRIMARYGROUP")
    else
        echo "Invalid group specified reverting to default!"
        USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "--user-group")
    fi
fi

# Ask about additional groups.
echo -n "Would you like the new user to be a part of any additional groups?  Leave blank if no additional groups are needed or enter additional groups in the format of GROUP1,GROUP2,... (NO SPACES) and press [ENTER]: "
read EXTRAGROUPS
# Remove spaces if the user entered any.
EXTRAGROUPS="${EXTRAGROUPS//[[:space:]]}"
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=''
IFS=, read -a TEMP <<< "$EXTRAGROUPS"
for G in "${TEMP[@]}"; do
    if [[ $(grep -c "^${g}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]]; then
        FINALEXTRAGROUPS="$FINALEXTRAGROUPS,$G"
    else
        echo "$G is an invalid user and will not be added."
    fi
done
if [[ ${#FINALEXTRAGROUPS[@]} -ge 1 ]]; then
    USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "-G" "${FINALEXTRAGROUPS:1}")
fi

# Ask about the home directory
read -p "Would you like to enter a new home directory for the user?  Leave blank to use the default of $HOME/$USERNAME or enter your own and press [ENTER]: " NEWHOME
if [[ ${#NEWHOME} -ge 1 ]]; then
    USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "-d" "$NEWHOME")
fi

# Add the username to the command
USERADDCOMMAND=("${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}" "$USERNAME")

# Add THE USER
echo "> ${USERADDCOMMAND[*]}"
"${USERADDCOMMAND[@]}"

echo "> passwd $USERNAME"
passwd "$USERNAME"

echo "> chfn $USERNAME"
chfn "$USERNAME"  # -f "$NAME"
```

Comment: The second script ended up being what I used.  However, I did have to remove the `--user-group` section so that the only time it responds is when they pass in valid groups.  Otherwise, there isn't a flag added.  Thanks for this it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

If the `man -s8 useradd` does not mention `--user-group` option available to use, then `-U` will not work. There's still another solution worth trying:

> The default behavior (if the -g, -N, and -U options are not specified)
>   is defined by the USERGROUPS_ENAB variable in /etc/login.defs.

Another way is, you have to chain the `useradd` command with a `groupadd` command with the same username supplied as parameters to both the commands.

**EDIT:**
This must work. First create the group and then create the user and add this new user to the group. Since, you are doing this in a script this should do the job very well.

Do this:

```
groupadd jaredm2
useradd -m -g jaredm2 jaredm2
```

Instead of this:

```
useradd -m --user-group jaredm2
```

Note that certain other programs which would've been installed in your OS, may have changed your binary or access to it or even created an alias for it. Your `which` output suggests that it is linked to the `useradd` binary in bin directory, precisely where it should be.

So I guess:

- the binary might have been changed or replaced by a process, by package installers or something else
- there's some mismatch between the binary version and the man page version(most likely if you have upgraded your OS improperly, at some point of time)

I think, the only solutions would be using the above pair of commands or changing the `useradd` binary you are using manually.

Comment: I previously had `-U` as part of the script before posting the question.  I tried the `--user-group` out of desperation.  The man page I have for user add says... `-U` will... `Create a group with the same name as the user, and add the user to this group.`

Comment: Did you try with the `/etc/login.defs`?

Comment: It is set to `yes`, but that still begs the question why can i copy and paste the command with success but not run from the script?

Comment: ok try the full path of the `useradd` binary in your script. I think there's some problem with the $PATH variable not being set properly.In your command line just do `which useradd` to find the location of useradd binary.

Comment: I have actually tried that as well :S and I've done an `echo "$PATH"` just to make sure that the path to useradd was there (and it was).  The `echo` was done from inside of the script not at the command.

Comment: just to make sure I did it correctly I did a `which useradd` to get the path for the `useradd` in use.  Is this correct?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from the debug mode.  Now it's saying the file isn't there, but again I can copy and paste the command from the debug mode with success.  It only fails from the script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18614/discussion-between-askmish-and-jared)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by your script you made ​​the use magic quotes `` `...` `` to execute your shell commands.

These quotes should only be used if you want to store the return of a command in a variable:
example the instruction below:

```
FINALCOMMAND=`echo "$FINALCOMMAND $USERNAME" | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed 's/^ *//g'`
```

Otherwise it is not necessary to use this quote and they can produce bugs like yours.

you can put in your script:

```
useradd $FINALCOMMAND
passwd $USERNAME
chfn $USERNAME
```

instead of:

```
`useradd $FINALCOMMAND`
`passwd $USERNAME`
`chfn $USERNAME`
```

Comment: switching the commands to `useradd $FINALCOMMAND
passwd $USERNAME
chfn $USERNAME`  produced this in the debugger...  `+ FINALCOMMAND='-m -U JaredM2'
+ useradd '-m -U JaredM2'
useradd: invalid option -- ' '
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN`

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your update with debug content, it seems like what you are doing is different from the script you posted.

Anyway, from the debug output, I suspect you're trying to run the adduser command using double quotes

```
"$FINALCOMMAND"
```

or maybe enclosed in backticks too, as that seems to be the only situation that triggers the "No such file or directory" error message.

Getting rid of the double quotes should fix the problem.

**p/s**: Don't use command substitution (``` `` ```) unless you're actually using the output (e.g. for testing or assigning to variables), or else something like this might happen

```
$ `echo Just saying hi`
Just: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the bug in your script, simply remove the line IFS=","

It is a misuse of the environment variable IFS (Internal Field Separator)

The script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Add a new user

FINALCOMMAND="-m"

#import useradd defaults...
. /etc/default/useradd

#Check if running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be ran as root"
    exit 1
fi

#Get the new users Name
#echo -n "Please enter the users First and Last Name and press [ENTER]: "
#read Name

#Get the new users username
echo "The username must be 4-20 characters."
echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
read USERNAME
while [ $(grep -c "^${USERNAME}:" /etc/passwd) -ge 1 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -le 3 ] || [ ${#USERNAME} -ge 21 ]
do
    echo " "
    echo "Error: Username is in use or invalid.  Please select a different username."
    echo " "
    echo -n "Please enter the users requested username and press [ENTER]: "
    read USERNAME   
done #USERNAME will be valid from this point

#ASK about the default shell now
echo -n "Enter the new shell if you would like one (currently $SHELL) or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read tempSHELL
if [ ${#tempSHELL} -ge 1 ]; then
    SHELL="$tempSHELL"
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND ""-s $SHELL"
fi

#ASK about a different primary group
echo "Would you like to enter a non-default primary user group? Defaults to creating a new group that matches the username"
echo "Enter a new Primary Group or leave blank for the default and press [ENTER]: "
read newPrimaryGroup

if [ ${#newPrimaryGroup} -eq 0 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND --user-group"
else
    if [ $(grep -c "^${newPrimaryGroup}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -g $newPrimaryGroup"
    else
        echo "Invalid group specified reverting to default!"
        FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND --user-group"
    fi
fi
#useradd -m --user-group jaredm2
#ASK about additional groups
echo "Would you like the new user to be a part of any additional groups?  Leave blank if no additional groups are needed or enter additional groups in the format of GROUP1,GROUP2,... (NO SPACES) and press [ENTER]: "
read extraGroups
#remove spaces if the user entered any
extraGroups="${extraGroups//[[:space:]]}"
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=""
#IFS=","
for g in $extraGroups
do
    if [ $(grep -c "^${g}" /etc/group) -ge 1 ]; then
        FINALEXTRAGROUPS="$FINALEXTRAGROUPS,$g"
    else
        echo "$g is invalid user will not be added..."
    fi
done
FINALEXTRAGROUPS=$(echo "$FINALEXTRAGROUPS" | tail -c +2)
if [ ${#FINALEXTRAGROUPS} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -G $FINALEXTRAGROUPS"
fi

#ASK about the home directory
echo "Would you like to enter a new home directory for the user?  Leave blank to use the default of $HOME/$USERNAME or enter your own and press [ENTER]: "
read NEWHOME

if [ ${#NEWHOME} -ge 1 ]; then
    FINALCOMMAND="$FINALCOMMAND -d $NEWHOME"
fi

#ADD the username to the command
FINALCOMMAND=`echo "$FINALCOMMAND $USERNAME" | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed 's/^ *//g'`
echo "useradd $FINALCOMMAND"
#PASSCOMMAND="sudo passwd $USERNAME"
#ADD THE USER
useradd $FINALCOMMAND

passwd $USERNAME

chfn $USERNAME
```